# extracting integer from nsstring

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

Debug log looks as follows.

```
2013-06-09 17:09:09.192 BridgeDeal[2430:11303] suito: 2K
2013-06-09 17:09:09.193 BridgeDeal[2430:11303] suit: 50
2013-06-09 17:09:09.193 BridgeDeal[2430:11303] suito: 2Q
2013-06-09 17:09:09.193 BridgeDeal[2430:11303] suit: 50
2013-06-09 17:09:09.194 BridgeDeal[2430:11303] suito: 3J
2013-06-09 17:09:09.194 BridgeDeal[2430:11303] suit: 51
```

The values for `suito` above are correct, but not the values for `suit` above. Instead for the values of `suit` I am hoping to get 2,2,3 .

```
for (int i = 0; i<3; i++) {
    NSInteger suit = [[self.cardList objectAtIndex:i ] characterAtIndex:0] ;
    NSLog(@"suito: %@", [self.cardList objectAtIndex:i ]);
    NSLog(@"suit: %d", suit);

}
```

`cardlist` is declared as follows.

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) NSMutableArray *cardList;
```

I have tried the following code but get the error: `bUnexpected type name 'NSRange'`

```
NSInteger suit = [[self.cardList objectAtIndex:i ] substringWithRange:NSRange(0,1)]  ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're getting is the ASCII code for the number. That's what the character is.

Your second section of code is better but use `NSMakeRange` or `(NSRange){0,1}`

Comment: Using NSRange){0,1} I get the following issue and funny results. `Incompatible pointer to integer conversion initializing 'NSInteger' (aka 'int') with an expression of 'NSString *'`

Comment: Sorry, forgot to say that the line you have returns a string, not an integer. If you want to get the integer you can add the call to 'integerValue' at the end.

Comment: Really you should store the data in a different way if you want to use the number as an array index...

Answer (score 1):

Change `NSLog(@"suit: %d",suit);` to `NSLog(@"suit: %d",suit - '0');`.

When you call characterAtIndex on the NSString object, it returns a unichar (unsigned short) variable; you then store that value in an NSInteger. You'd think that would give you an error. The reason it doesn't is because unichar (and in C, char) variables are actually integers (in this case, unichar is just typedef'd an unsigned short). Each character ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', etc.) has a different number associated with it. It so happens that the number associated with the character '2' in the ASCII character set is 50, and the number associated with '3' is 51. Since (in ASCII anyway) the characters for the digits '0' through '9' are all sequential, you can "hack" your way to get the actual number represented by subtracting the value for '0' from the value for your character (`suit - '0'`). Since the value for '0' (in ASCII) is 48, subtracting it will give you 2, 2, and 3 instead of 50, 50, and 51.

If you are representing card suits as numbers, you might consider storing them in the array itself as numbers instead of strings.

Comment: I haven't tried your "hack", but it makes some sense. I sure wish there was a nicer way to do this, especially because I don't just want results in NSLog, but I want to use the result as the index of an NSArray. I'll have to try your "hack".

Comment: @zerowords The "hack" isn't dependent on NSLog. You can also change your earlier line of code. `NSInteger suit = [[self.cardList objectAtIndex:i ] characterAtIndex:0] - '0';`

But as someone else mentioned, you might as well just store the suit as an integer.